# Grub keeps installing boot manager on my SSD

Tags: grub-efi

I have an SSD and a harddrive on my laptop. I have installed windows 10 on my SSD and i just installed Ubuntu on my HDD. While installing, i chose to install boot manager on my HDD but it still keeps installing the boot manager on my SSD. How do i fix this?
Here's the lsblk output :-
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop1         7:1    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop2         7:2    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop3         7:3    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop4         7:4    0   9.1M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
loop5         7:5    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop6         7:6    0  96.6M  1 loop /snap/core/9804
loop7         7:7    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop8         7:8    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0 843.6G  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0  87.9G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 237.4G  0 part
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   800M  0 part

Comment: Could you open a terminal and type `lsblk` and then **edit** your question above and add the output please?

Comment: Ubiquity installer options only work with BIOS. Did you create gpt partitions on HDD with an ESP? Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.
Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive.
If you have ESP on second drive, you can just reinstall grub, either manually or withBoot-Repair's advanced mode & full reinstall to correct drive.

Comment: I don't use bios i have an UEFI system and all my disks are GPT. I am new to linux so i don't understand what ESP is. Would you tell me what ESP is?Is there any way to install grub without losing any data or settings from my linux installation as i spent a lot of time customizing it to my taste.